# Android HMAC-SHA1 Different than Standard Java HMAC-SHA1

Tags: java, android, sha1, hmac

I'm having issues with some HMAC on android.  I am using the SHA1 algorithm with the following code which shows up all over the web when searching for android hmac-sha1.

```
        String base_string = "This is a test string";
        String key = "testKey";
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), mac.getAlgorithm());
            mac.init(secret);
            byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(base_string.getBytes());

            String enc = new String(digest);

            // Base 64 Encode the results
            String retVal = Base64.encodeBase64String(enc.getBytes());
            Log.v(TAG, "String: " + base_string);
            Log.v(TAG, "key: " + key);
            Log.v(TAG, "result: " + retVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

To test this code I created a simple standard Java program with it (replacing the Log.v calls with System.out.println calls of course) so I can compare vs. the android version. In both instances I'm using the same test values for the base_string and key.

In addition I have verified the encoded results from the standard Java with some PHP functions and a validation server (using some OAuth tokens). The code works fine in the standard Java program however it does not work in the Android program.  I have done a lot of searching and cant figure out what is wrong.  Anyone ever experience this?

Here are the results from standard java and android...

- Java (and PHP): `fH/+pz0J5XcPZH/d608zGSn7FKA=`
- Android Program: `fH/vv73vv709Ce+/vXcPZH/vv73vv71PMxkp77+9FO+/vQ==`

Looking into it a bit more I am sure it is the hmac function and not the Base64 encode where it gets messed up as comparing those hmac values the Android version has all sorts of extra spaces and other unknown character symbols vs. the Java program.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't find method `android.util.Base64.encodeBase64String(...)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose this is a String encoding problem.

What are you doing here?

```
        String enc = new String(digest);

        // Base 64 Encode the results
        String retVal = Base64.encodeBase64String(enc.getBytes());
```

You turn the bytes in a string, and then back to a byte array again (which you then base-64 encode).

Instead, do this:

```
        String retVal = Base64.encodeBase64String(digest);
```

In general, never ever user `String.getBytes()` or `new String(byte[])` if you want a portable program. And never try to convert an arbitrary byte arrays (which was not a string before) to a string (other than something like Base64).

Comment: Wow! So simple! I knew it was going to be something like that but I was really scratching my head.  Thanks! That fixed the problem right away.

Comment: Where do you find the method encodeBase64String()? I don't find it anywhere .

Comment: @Gabrielle: I simply copied this part from the question, I don't know which base64-library was used here. But they all should give the same result, as this is a clearly specified algorithm.

Comment: Even if I download the package org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 and add it to my project, I always get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String. I cannot find where is the mistake.

Comment: I suppose you have runtime class path problems. Try to ask this as a new question, as it does not relate at all to this one.

Comment: Can't find method `android.util.Base64.encodeBase64String(...)`

Comment: Eventually I used `android.util.Base64.encode(digest, Base64.DEFAULT)`

Comment: Also, there's no need to convert to String and back to byte array.

Comment: The Base64 library used could be from Apache Commons Codec.